# How can I ignore chktex warnings based on their number?

Tags: auctex

I keep getting following warning message: `Wrong length of dash may have been used. [8]` from `chktex`. How can I ignore this warning message that has number 8.

From command call: I can do `chktex -n8` , which suppresses it but I am not sure how I can add `-n8` flag during emacs uses `chktex`.

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/641076/127048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `TeX-command-list` and its doc string where `ChkTex` is defined. Assuming that that's what you want to change, it can be done fairly easily with `setf` (but it might be easier to use `Customize`):

```el
(setf (cadr (assoc "ChkTeX" TeX-command-list)) "chktex -v6 -n8 %s")
```

The `assoc` picks out the `ChkTeX` entry of `TeX-command-list` and the `setf` changes its `cadr` (the second element of the list) to the new command where I've added `-n8` to what was there originally.

Untested, except that I can see the change correctly happening in `TeX-comman-list`.

Comment: What does `cadr` stands for?

Comment: `C-h i g(elisp)List elements` wil tell you about `cadr` and many other such functions: ` -- Function: cadr cons-cell
     This is the same as ‘(car (cdr CONS-CELL))’ or ‘(nth 1 CONS-CELL)’.`. It gives you the second element of a list (assuming that list has two or more elements).